# Ubuntu 18.04 Enable Tap-to-click on Unity desktop

Tags: unity, touchpad

I like the look of the Unity desktop more than GNOME, but with Unity, I can't use tap-to-click on my mousepad, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 20):

Well, I don't know if Unity has some option for it, hopefully someone will answer on that one. But you can enable it from command line:

1. list devices with `xinput list`, and find the touchpad name in the output.
2. use a `xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`, where the text in first quotes `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` needs to be replaced with touchpad name you got in step 1.

This will only work till reboot, so you'll need to add the command from step 2 to autostart.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I upvoted your post by tapping my touchpad, thanks.

Comment: works on ubuntu 21.04 unity 7 too , thanks

Comment: I love you bro haha working on Ubuntu 18 after a desktop reinstall

Answer (score 6):

Late Answer for those who see themselfes stumbling in this wide narrow sea.

If you are using a Synaptics device best thing would be installing the Synaptics drivers - The options you need will be added to the general settings under "Mouse and Touchpad".

EDIT: Apparently [xf86-input-synaptics is not a synaptics driver](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/12/xf86-input-synaptics-is-not-synaptics.html), but still did the job for others and my machine(xps15).

To do so, first update everything

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install the driver with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

In case that doen't work because you are missing dependencies, go for the HWE version;

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
```

finally, restart and you should find the extended standard options in the system settings.

Comment: This is a bad advice, synaptics is long obsoleted in preference of libinput, and [has nothing to do with synaptics hw](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/12/xf86-input-synaptics-is-not-synaptics.html).

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: Same for me on my xps15. As long as it works - but I will ad that to my answer

Comment: Works for 20.04 as well.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use Unity in 18.04 as it is discontinued and you can customize Gnome quite a bit to emulate most of the features anyway, but, to each his own.

In any case, did you uninstall the Gnome utilities while installing Unity? If not, and you are using Xorg, you should see the option for **tap-to-click** in the **Mouse & Touchpad** settings.

[image: mouse & touchpad settings]

Comment: Sure gnome 'CAN' be great, but thats not the point. For me it was unusable due to all the lags, slow transitions and even lags on scrolling - despite the use of my GPU. It's just very poorly optimized for performance on new machines.

Comment: This setting does _not_ help in Unity. It only affects the GNOME desktop.